# Кнопки на окнах

Tags: оформление, ubuntu

Как переместить кнопки на окнах с левой стороны на правую?

Answer (score 1):

```
gconf-editor /apps/metacity
```

Найти в general и изменить ключ `button_layout`, с `close, minimize, maximize`: на `minimize, maximize, close`. Перезагрузить.

Answer (score 1):

ПКМ на рабочий стол, "Изменить фон рабочего стола" > "Тема" > А дальше найдите тему, у которой кнопки управления окном располагаются справа.з.ы. это как вариант.

Answer (score 0):

Справа - налево:

```
gconftool-2 --set "/apps/metacity/general/button_layout" --type string "menu:minimize,maximize,close"
```

Слева - направо:

```
gconftool-2 --set "/apps/metacity/general/button_layout" --type string "close,maximize,minimize:menu"
```

Answer (score 0):

Скачай **Ubuntu-Tweak.**

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:tualatrix/ppasudo apt-get updatesudo apt-get install ubuntu-tweak
```

Ты будешь приятно удивлён!